# Azure configuration for a university student

Tags: azure

Hopefully my question is in the right forum here. I've just checked out the pricing model of windows azure and checked out the different configuration options:
[image]
http://www.windowsazure.com/de-de/pricing/calculator/

I have been working as a developer for almost two years now and worked a lot with IIS and the WPF technology. As a little private project I checked out HTML 5 and JS with MVC4 Web API and wondered what azure configuration I'd need to host a MVC 4 Web API project. Would it be rather a virtual machine or a full calculator? What benefits grants one over another?

I am going to start my studies soon, so I'd like the cheapest I can possibly get. I won't use it a lot (mainly for testing reasons), as well I think there won't be too much traffic either. Would a virtual machine also include the possibility of using IIS?

Could I also run a MVC project with something else than VM/full calculator?

And what would happen if for some reason my traffic just explodes? Would my services just be shut down until I increase the power of my machine? Or would I just get a huge bill and be surprised quite a lot?

Comment: The "full calculator" is just a way to look at all of the prices at once, it isn't something you can buy.

Comment: "full calculator" seems a pretty odd term for a computer to me, so I could have thought of that already. I watched the site in german and there the translation is less odd. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use websites.
You can start with 10 Web Sites absolutely free! So this is the cheapest. And it certainly supports MVC4 Web API.

Comment: And the Free website has a limit on resources, so it shuts down when there is too much traffic. You can scale up, but then you will have to pay

Answer (score 0):

For starter you can get a [3 month trial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) with enough credits to start.  By default you'll have a spending limit on your account.  This mean if you start to get too much traffic your services will shut down and you won't have to pay any extra.  I think you can configure how much you are willing to pay but I never tried, it is still the default which is 0$.

You should start with Shared Web Sites and move to reserved instance, VM or web role later if you ever need to scale up or out.